# What's Unit8Array in AWS S3 bucket response

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am calling the AWS S3 getObject function: `(AWS.Request) getObject(params = {}, callback)`

I wrote this:

```
getMenuJson() {
   this.s3.getObject({
     Bucket: 'improd-image-pipeline',
     Key: 'remoteUX/qa/menus/v1/menus.json',
     ResponseContentType: 'application/json',
   }, (err, data) => {
     if (err) {
       this.$log.log(err);
     } else {
       this.$log.log(data, JSON.parse(data.Body));
     }
   });
 }
```

This is the console output, I try to print the data and the actual menus.json file on the S3 console.
[image]

The return data if I printed like this: JSON.parse(data.Body), this is the result.

```
 {  
   "menus":[  
      {  
         "name": "Flat Collections Example",
         "menuId": "aaa-3656-4a32-bdda-e2e016cf35ee"
      },
      {  
         "name":"P3",
         "menuId": "aaa-f5fc-4e18-9089-47e43a4237e8"
      },
      {  
         "name": "Tabbed Menu Example",
         "menuId": "aaa-768a-40bd-a9f4-b633f3679c36"
      }
   ]
}
```

But, how to understand the response body: Unit8Array, and how it's interpreted to a actual json formatted data?

**I am using Angular.toJson(data.Body) and this function didn't understand it, but JSON.parse(data.Body) will get the correct result.**

Comment: are you setting the correct contentType when uploading to s3?

Comment: I tried with contentType: 'application/json', still no luck

Comment: Is `.getObject()` a wrapper for `fetch()`?

Comment: An Uint8Array is a typed array that has no representation in JSON. You'll need to create a new Array from this typed array (Array.from()) in order to parse it in JSON.

Answer (score 2):

It's a JavaScript Typed Array which represents an array of 8-bit unsigned integers.

AWS.Request.getObject() return value of data.Body can be any of the following: Buffer, Typed Array, Blob, String, ReadableStream.

You can check [AWS docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getObject-property) for more info.

In your case it's **Uint8Array** (JavaScript typed array).

Understand more: [JavaScript Typed Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays), [Uint8Array object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array)